# I would like to read a config file and save the information in an object - this solution alright?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, configuration

at first I would like to try to explain my plan: Sometimes I just have to change some static values in my code (lets say, the path to a folder with data my program needs or the url to upload something) and after that I have to compile again. If lets say the url is changed where I want to upload the files and the url is like I said static in my code - well I have to change it in Visual Studio and compile it again...and again and again. Well thats why I think this is NOT a good idea. It would be better to make a config file (a file where I can store all my values/information that I need) and read this file every time my program is starting. Now I could make changes without compiling - I just have to edit my config file.

I thought I choose the XML format, I could take an normal textfile, but I think an XML is more secure and easier to read if it gets complex. Now there is maybe one problem with this: I have to 'hardcode' the path to my XML file. I think I will never change the path to the config file, but what if I would? Then I have to change the path in my code again. Is there maybe a smarter solution for this?

The next step would be that I have to read the XML file on every startup. Now I would like to know what is the best OOP solution to get the information and use it? I thought I make a class (lets say **Myconfig**) and in this class I have only final variables (I think final is readonly in c#) with getter and setter. I will create a new **Myconfig** on every startup and I will parse the XML file - while Im parsing and getting the information Im using the setter to save the information in the class variable. After Im done I have an object with **all** the information and now I could send/use this object everywhere to get these information (let say with **Myconfig.Url** , **Myconfig.Path** ...).

Well thats my plan :-) Im really new to this, Im sure this is not perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sort of configuration file is fully supported in .NET, and you don't need to write any custom code to use it. You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx

Comment: ah this is new to me, thank you. And this is the better way to make it yes?

Comment: Absolutely. This is exactly the situation it is intended for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a configuration file with the ConfigurationManager class to access values in it. .NET has already provided this solution for you - there is no reason for you to write one yourself.